# Controlling touches in CCScrollLayer (cocos2d iOS)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scroll, ccscrolllayer

I have a CCScrollLayer in my app which contains movable sprites (they can be dragged & dropped). The issue is that when dragging the sprites too far, the CCScrollLayer starts scrolling. I am trying to disable the CCScrollLayer from scrolling as long as I am dragging those sprites. The disabling works by using

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:sender];
```

I get the sender from method

```
- (void)scrollLayerScrollingStarted:(CCScrollLayer *)sender {
    //...
}
```

I cannot enable the CSScrollLayer again, tried with this but no result:

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:scrollLayer priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];
```

I am using v1.0.1 (stable version)

Comment: I found this as well: http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=1267 which states an official bug report. Using the CCTouchDispatcher from there does not work. Does anybody have a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass CCScrollLayer and add an enabled property boolean. Just override the touch methods that CCScrollLayer uses to start its sliding. For example

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     if(self.enabled)
           return [super ccTouchBegan:touch withEvent:event];
     else
           return NO;
}
```